# "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." while trying to update

Tags: 8, upgrading

I'm not great a Drupal, but I was trying to install some updates.

I put my site in to maintenance mode.

Copied the entire directory for in to `/var/www/html/backups/`
Backed up the database with `mysqldump -u <username> -p <site> > /var/www/html/<backup folder>/backup.sql`

Then I cleared out everything in the web directory.
I downloaded the `.tar.gz` file from [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.8.3), untarred it and copied it in to my website directory.

Finally I copied `/sites`, `.htaccess`, and `robots.txt` from my backup in to my website directory.

When I go to run `update.php` I get to the initial update page I click `continue` I get `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`

At one point I was able to try to install updates and got the error:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /update.php/start?id=37&op=do_nojs&op=do
StatusText: OK
ResponseText:
```

I even tried deleting everything from my website directory and just copying everything in my backup back in, but that doesn't seem to fix the problem. I can't even view `/admin/reports/dblog` to try and get more information as suggested by a different solution.

Does anyone have any suggestions or did I just totally screw myself over?

Comment: Are you running the correct version of PHP? Drupal dropped support for PHP 5 in May of last year. See: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/php-requirements. You can view log messages in the watchdog table of your database.

Comment: Yes, per `php -v` I'm running `PHP 7.3.15-2`. I don't think I can view the log messages because as I mentioned when I try to navigate to `/admin/reports/dblog` I get the same unexpected error message.

Comment: What I meant was, if you can view your database you can find the logs in the *watchdog* table. (This is assuming you don't have access to your PHP error log.)

Comment: Ahh, okay. My `sql` is even worse than my drupal skills so I'm not 100% what I'm looking for. `select * from watchdog;` gives me the table and the last line is `#21 {main}";} |        3 |      | https://domain.com/update.php/start?_format=json&id=41&op=do&op=do_nojs                  | https://domain.com/update.php/start?id=41&op=start                          | <IP Address>  | 1583600827 |` followed by a bunch of `---+---`

Comment: Reading your issue again, you didn't mention that you had copied over your non-core modules or themes when you attempted your update. Could that have been the problem? As for reverting to your backup, try truncating the cache tables in the database. Also restart your browser; sometimes error pages can get stuck in browser cache.

Comment: I did not copy any `modules` or `themes` back over. The only thing in `/modules` and `/themes` is `README.TXT`.  I've tried multiple browsers with no difference.

Comment: If you have drush installed, you can easily view your watchdog log with `drush ws`. Execute `drush help ws` for options to drill down on your watchdog logs.